# RazorPDF - How to set background-color for some tags like cell, paragraph etc

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc, itext, background-color, razorpdf

I'm just trying to create a simple xml layout with RazorPDF, but I couldn't find any way to set background color for some tags.

This is what I've tried,

```
<paragraph style="background-color:red">
   <chunk bgcolor="red">sampletext</chunk>
</paragraph>
```

My action is simply,

```
public ActionResult Pdf() 
{
     return new PdfResult();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If using a table the backgroundcolor="#808080" attribute sets the backcolor, while style="color:blue" or red="0" green="0" blue="255" sets the textcolor.

```
<table width="100%" cellpadding="1.0" cellspacing="1.0">
<row>
    <cell backgroundcolor="#FFFF00" borderwidth="0.5" left="true" right="true" top="true" bottom="true" size="12.0">
        <chunk style="font-family:Times;font-weight:bold;font-size:9pt">
            Customer
        </chunk>
    </cell>
    <cell backgroundcolor="#FFFF00" borderwidth="0.5" left="true" right="true" top="true" bottom="true" size="12.0">
        <chunk style="font-family:Times;font-weight:bold;font-size:9pt;color:blue">
            Customer
        </chunk>
    </cell>
    <cell backgroundcolor="#FFFF00" borderwidth="0.5" left="true" right="true" top="true" bottom="true" size="12.0">
        <chunk red="0" green="0" blue="255" style="font-family:Times;font-weight:bold;font-size:9pt">
            Customer
        </chunk>
    </cell>
</row></table>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    <paragraph  style="font-family:Helvetica;font-size:14; border:1px" align="center">
        <chunk red="0" green="0" blue="255" >@ViewBag.Title</chunk>
    </paragraph>
```

Comment: This will only change the font color, not the background color. please check your answer before post it here.